# How do I write a python decorator that depends on a class attribute? Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am writing a class that takes an external object from an api, performs some processing on that object, exposes some useful methods, then writes the processed object to a database.  In cases where the external object no longer exists, I want the class methods to use the data from the database record.

This is causing a lot of repeated, simple code in the class methods:

```
class Synchronised_object:
    def __init__(self, obj=None, rec=None):

        self.object = obj
        self.record = rec

    def a(self):
        if self.object:
            return self.object.a
        else:
            return self.record['a']

    def b(self):
        if self.object:
            return self.object.b.upper()
        else:
            return self.record['b']
```

Repeated, simple code in functions sounds like a great use case for decorators, but in this case the decorator code would depend on an attribute of the instantiated class object, which appears to be problematical from everything I read on here and elsewhere.

Is there any way to write a decorator that depends on self.object?  If not, is there another way to reduce the repetition of the "if self.object.... else return self.record[name]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really just want a method that handles the logic of deferring to the record. Something like:

```
class SynchronisedObject:
    def __init__(self, obj=None, rec=None):
        self.object = obj
        self.record = rec
    def _proxy(self, attr):
        if self.object:
            return getattr(self.object, attr)
        return self.record[attr]
    def a(self):
        return self._proxy("a")
    def b(self):
        return self._proxy("b").upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying the function of [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77945138/12439683) which you can use to make your code even slimmer.
In case all your functions follow the same pattern you can use the [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) functions to skip also the function definition

#### Using partial

```
from functools import partial

def _proxy(self, attr):
    if self.object:
        return getattr(self.object, attr)
    return self.record[attr]


class Synchronised_object:
    def __init__(self, obj=None, rec=None):

        self.object = obj
        self.record = rec

    a = partial(_proxy, "a")

    # if you need some post post-processing
    _b = partial(_proxy, "b")

    def b(self):
        return self._b().upper()
```

---

#### Using a decorator

As you asked for a decorator you could write it like this, in which it adds the retrieved value to the function signature which you can use for further postprocessing.
I think you could also manage to avoid passing the "attr" string to the decorator but that goes out of scope here :)

```
def aware_getter(attr):
    def decorator(func):
       def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if self.object:
               res = getattr(self.object, attr)
           else:
               res = self.record[attr]
           return func(self, res, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

class SynchronisedObject:
    def __init__(self, obj=None, rec=None):
        self.object = obj
        self.record = rec
    @aware_getter("a")
    def a(self, res):
        return res
    @aware_getter("b")
    def b(self, res):
        return res.upper()
```